# Почему VISUAL STUDIO 2015 копирует лишние сборки в папку с программой?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

В проекте были подключены стороне сборки, я удалил их из References проекта, но при Rebuild, VS продолжает их класть в папку со скомпилированной программой.

Почему?

Answer (score 3):

VISUAL STUDIO копирует все зависимые сборки, в том числе и все зависимости дочерних сборок. Если всё же вы сомневаетесь, сделайте перед началом пересборки Clean или удалите все папки в директории /bin вашего проекта.